# Apache CXF client "connection reset" with long requests

Tags: java, soap, jax-ws, cxf

I have a SOAP web service.

When calling it from SoapUI the request works well, whatever the size of the message content.

If I make the same requests from Apache CXF client code it works with small requests but I get a "connection reset" if my message content is too long, with the following exception:

```
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.InputRecord.read(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readDataRecord(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.AppInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(Unknown Source)
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(Unknown Source)
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTPHeader(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.handleResponseInternal(HTTPConduit.java:1606)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.handleResponse(HTTPConduit.java:1532)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.close(HTTPConduit.java:1440)
... 37 more
```

Any idea on what could cause it or how to debug it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is caused by the [chunking mechanism](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/client-http-transport-including-ssl-support.html#ClientHTTPTransport%28includingSSLsupport%29-ANoteAboutChunking) which gets enabled by CXF when the request size is beyond a threshold and which is not supported on server side.

This chunking can be [disabled programmatically](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/client-http-transport-including-ssl-support.html#ClientHTTPTransport%28includingSSLsupport%29-Usingjavacode) but there is a bug in CXF which makes that [programmatic configuration is not taken into account in case of SSL connection](http://tonyyan.wordpress.com/2013/04/24/cxf-conduit-setting-for-ssl-and-non-ssl-client/).

The solution is to disable chunking via a [spring configuration file](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/client-http-transport-including-ssl-support.html#ClientHTTPTransport%28includingSSLsupport%29-UsingConfiguration).

Comment: I'm using the 2.7.18 version of the cxf library i'm still facing the same issue, but ur solution is for spring framework and I'm not using any framework, is there an alternative solution or approach that i can try ?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

`-Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.2`

or whatever version the server supports.